# ORA-01873: the leading precision returning INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql

This is quite different from other question ona same argument.

I Have a PL/SQL Function returning an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.
Oracle does not allow specifying precision of the returned type, but I suspect it tries to CAST the returned value to the default INTERVAL precision in the RETURN statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function CV_NETSIU.dateDiff(pts1 timestamp, pts2 timestamp) return interval day to second
is
   ts1     timestamp;
   ts2     timestamp;
   tsStart timestamp;
   tsStop  timestamp;
   tsNow   timestamp := systimestamp;
   diff    interval day(6) to second;
begin
   --
   if pts1 = to_timestamp('01/01/0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy') then ts1 := tsnow; else ts1 := pts1; end if;
   if pts2 = to_timestamp('01/01/0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy') then ts2 := tsnow; else ts2 := pts2; end if;
   --
   if ts2 > ts1 
   then
       tsStart := ts1;
       tsStop  := ts2;
   else 
       tsStart := ts2;
       tsStop  := ts1;
   end if;
   diff := tsStop - tsStart;
   return diff;
end;
/
```

When called with dates differing more then 100 days, ORA-01873 is raised at the RETURN statement (not at the row calculating the diff.

```
select datediff(sysdate, sysdate - 300) from dual

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
ORA-06512: at "CV_NETSIU.DATEDIFF", line 23
```

Any idea how to force the return type to the non-default DAY(6) value?

Thanks

Maurizio

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Your function seems to work for me in Oracle 12.1.

Comment: @vscoder - did you try with inputs that result in an interval longer than 100 days? That is the only problem - if the interval is shorter, then the function works fine. I ask because I also use 12.1, but **not patched** since I am not a paying customer of Oracle. It is possible that your version is patched, and this is a bug that has been fixed, but it is also possible that you just didn't stress the function enough to hit the bug.

Comment: Yes, I used Jan 1, 1958 to Jan 3, 2021, got this diff:+023011 00:00:00.000000. I did not create the procedure, run this as PL/SQL with DECLARE instead of 'create function'

Comment: @vscoder - I don't think it's the same thing. You said "your function seems to work" but you didn't actually try the function, you tried something else.

Comment: Yes, I see now it is the return value that was the problem, my bad.

Comment: I closed the question as a DUPLICATE (not easy to find, but I was able to find it). Note the answer from Wernfried Domscheit (posted in 2015, five years later than the question itself) in the linked thread: exactly for your purpose, Oracle has the different data type `dsinterval_unconstrained`. I just tested your code with this data type for the return value, and it works as required.

Comment: Great Job!!! That was the answer!!!. Buried in PL/SQL reference. Thanks